# How to make sense of, and then effectively use the console warnings and errors in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I (an amateur home developer) am using Vue for about two or three years (recently with the quasar framework) and one of my main problems is how to make sense, and then actually use the warnings or errors I get in the console. Here is an example from a moment ago:

[image]

I finally found the `row` that was causing the problem, but I had to track it in the code and remember what I recently changed to pinpoint the error. This is just an example to illustrate the general problem.

In Python, when I see an error, I also see which exact line triggered it. In my IDE it is enough to click on it and I am there.

I am sure that the console information above also make sense for Vue but at no place I can see the actual line causing the problem.

**How should I read this console log to find the erroneous line in my Vue code?**

Answer (score 0):

#### Property or method "props" is not defined

> ```
> [Vue warn]: Property or method "props" is not defined on the instance but
> referenced during render. [...]
>
> found in
>
> ---> <MainLayout>
>        <App> at src/App.vue
>          <Root>
> ```

This indicates `<MainLayout>`'s `template` contains a reference to "`props`", which is not declared in the component's `data` or `props` (or in `setup()` if using the Composition API). For example:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ props }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    foo: String,
    // "props" not declared here
  },
  data() {
    return {
      bar: 1,
      // "props" not declared here
    }
  },
  setup() {
    return {
      // "props" not declared here
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Cannot read property 'row' of undefined

> ```
> [Vue warn]: Error in render. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined"
>
> found in
>
> ---> <MainLayout>
>        <App> at src/App.vue
>          <Root>
> ```

This indicates `<MainLayout>`'s `template` contains a sub-property reference to an object that is `undefined` (e.g., `myUndefinedObj.row`). Given the first warning above, that object is probably `props`:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ props.row }}</div>
          ^^^^^^
</template>
```

I'm guessing you actually have a `row` prop declared in `props`, and you're trying to reference it in the template. You can access `props` or `data` directly in the template without any prefixes:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ row }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    row: Number
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Error location

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined
>    at Proxy.render (MainLayout.vue?1074:54)
>    [...]
> ```

The stacktrace in the last warning indicates the filename and location of the error in the form of `FILENAME?LINE:COLUMN`:

```
MainLayout.vue?1074:54
   ^            ^    ^
filename        |    |
               line  |
                    column
```

Many modern IDEs show line number and column in the status bar at the bottom. Visual Studio Code shows them in the bottom right corner:

[image: VS Code status bar]

Clicking on that line indicator box opens a prompt to jump to a specific line number and column in `:`-delimited form, so you could copy-paste the line/column from the error (`1074:54`) into the prompt to jump to the exact location indicated.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. I will create a component with your information and show what the line in the last part of your answer shows. The main problem is that `MainLayout.vue` has only 250 lines, and when I access the one pointed out by the error (1074 in the case above), I end up in the source of Vue and not in my component.